# Help on Objective C? My app keeps crashing?

Tags: objective-c, crash, avaudioplayer

I am creating an app for the Iphone/Itouch, but I keep on running into a couple of major leaks that just crash the app. In my game, right when I press play (from the home screen)It goes to another page that has the game on it. But, right after it appears, ind the console I get a Warning: Memory level=1. What could be happening? Here is my ViewDidLoad Method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
bulletArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
pos = CGPointMake(0.0,-5.0);


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GloriousMorning" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
//float effects_Volume = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"effectsVolume"];
//theAudio.volume = effects_Volume;
[theAudio play];
```

}

And also, a second question, since my game is a shooting game, the user presses a button titled "Fire". But, every time I test my app on a device, It crashes when I press the fire button. Here is my code for the fire button.

```
-(IBAction)Fire {   
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gunShot" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
//float effects_Volume = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"effectsVolume"];
//theAudio.volume = effects_Volume;
[theAudio play];


//IBOutlet UIImageView *newBullet = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bullet.png"]];
UIImageView *newBullet = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bullet.png"]];
newBullet.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10.0, 10.0);
newBullet.center = CGPointMake(239.0, 236.0);
[bulletArray addObject:newBullet];
[self.view addSubview:newBullet];
```

}

First, I create a sound. Then, I place a bullet right where the gun is currently located, and add it to an array so that every .01 of a second, in another bit of code, I can run through the array and check every bullet to detect collision.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!!!

The error when I click the Fire Button that makes the app crash is this:

GDB: Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will retry after a 'continue'(unknown error loading shared library "

And Also I think I am making a huge leak when I try to play the audio, at least that's what someone told me. (If that is the case, please tell me how to fix it)

Answer (score 0):

You alloc'd theAudio so you need to release it when you are done. Might be better to make that a ivar so you don't have to set up and tear down the audio every time they press the fire button.